# automatic conversion of xfig to tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, xfig

I have a large collection (hundreds) of partially quite old xfig pictures. Though I really like the xfig program I would like to move to some more up-to-date picture format like TikZ. So I would like to ask if someone has a good idea for an automatic conversion tool. Ideally, some shell srcipt or so... Then problem (?) is that many of the xfig pictures have LaTeX overlays.

EDIT: this might be too long for a comment on Mark's answer, so I post it here as an edit:

Here is a sample of a xfig which simply produces an error

## FIG 3.2  Produced by xfig version 3.2.5b

```
Landscape
Center
Metric
A4
52.00
Single
-2
1200 2
3 0 0 3 0 7 50 -1 -1 0.000 0 1 0 3
1 1 4.00 60.00 150.00
7650 3375 6975 4275 7650 5625
0.000 1.000 0.000
```

the script gives some tikz command requesting an error

> Package pgf Error: Arrow end type ``triangle 45'' unknown.

So, of course, I can edit now by hand several arrows and so, but I would like to have it more automatic... :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a utility just for this called [`fig2tikz`](http://kogs-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/~meine/software/figpy/fig2tikz). From the web page it seems that LaTeX overlays should be supported, and I'd be interested to know if it does.

Running `fig2tikz` on the code you supply in the question yields:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm]

% objects at depth 50:
\draw[thick,arrows=-triangle 45,black] (17,7.5) .. controls (15.5,9.5) .. (17,12.5);

\end{tikzpicture}%
```

By placing this in a minimal document (note the `arrows` library)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
%%% Code generated by fig2tikz
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm]

% objects at depth 50:
\draw[thick,arrows=-triangle 45,black] (17,7.5) .. controls (15.5,9.5) .. (17,12.5);

\end{tikzpicture}%
%%% End of code
\end{document}
```

the following is generated:

[image]

Comment: Dear Mark: thank for the hint. Unfortunately, the script is not that perfect. It needs a lot of editing afterwards. But it is a start.

Comment: xfig can also save to SVG I think, in which case you can try opening the resultant SVG in Inkscape, which in turn can export to TikZ with the appropriate plugin. I have no idea if the output will be better or worse than fig2tikz, but it can still all be scripted.

Comment: What kind of things need editing? It may be that there's just no natural mapping for certain things in `.fig` files. It may be a good idea to link to an xfig file that doesn't convert well.

Comment: Dear Mark, I included some silly example. It seems that having won arrows is not supported...

Comment: `fig2tikz` works fine on your example, so long as you use `\usetikzlibrary{arrows}`.

Comment: Please see the updated answer. It may be that a number the problems you are having are due to features that need to be loaded from TikZ libraries.

Comment: Dear Mark: my stupidity. I was not aware of the additional libraries needed by tikz. Now it indeed works. So I will give it a second try. Thanks very much

Comment: No problem. I was surprised that fig2tikz doesn't have a flag that makes it spit out complete LaTeX files that compile without modification.

Comment: I know that SX discourages "me too" comments, but I have to say that this deserves to be more widely known!

Comment: Notice that the link above is not working --- I have found a similar (still trying to compile) fig2pgf in the sourceforge of pgf, but no traces of fig2tikz... anyone have a link?

Comment: That's a 500 error, indicating that the server is hitting an error rather than the document being gone. Give it a day or two.

Comment: I sent the webmaster an email and he kindly fixed the 500. The link did change slightly though, so I have updated it.

Comment: From the author: Note that fig2tikz is *much* more powerful than the outdated, obviously unmaintained [fig2pgf](http://pgf.cvs.sourceforge.net/pgf/fig2pgf/), which is available via the PGF CVS repository, ever was.

Answer (score 6):

Releases 3.2.6 of [xfig / fig2dev](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcj/) and newer can export to tikz. A standalone tex file is produced with `fig2dev -L tikz -P f.fig f.tex`. Omit `-P` to produce code for inclusion in a tex-file.

Answer (score 2):

I have two alternative propositions to Mark's suggestion.

a. Since my understanding is that you have hundreds of old Xfig pictures you probably want to automatize that. I would use Transfig utility (should have come with your Xfig installation) in particular **fig2dev** to convert your files into **eps** files and then use [eps2pgf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eps2pgf/)
utility to convert to PGF code (which is almost TikZ right)

```
cd my_pictures_dir
for i in *.fig
  do 
    fig2dev -L eps $i `basename $i .fig`.eps
    java -jar eps2pgf.jar `basename $i .fig`.eps `basename $i .fig`.pgf
  done
```

I have not tested the solution so YMMV.

b. The second option is that you pick some other intermediate format

```
$ fig2dev -help 
fig2dev Version 3.2 Patchlevel 5a
General Options (all drivers):
  -L language   choose output language (this must be first)
                Available languages are:
                  box cgm eepic eepicemu emf epic eps ge gif 
                  ibmgl dxf jpeg latex map mf mmp mp pcx 
                  pdf pdftex pdftex_t pic pictex png ppm ps pstex 
                  pstex_t ptk shape sld svg textyl tiff tk tpic 
                  xbm xpm
```

which can be easer converted to TikZ or PGF. I do not use TikZ on the regular basis nor I am familiar enough with the library to make a correct selection.

Comment: Are the LaTeX overlays preserved with these methods? If lucky they would be preserved in the EPS route but I'm not sure if they get mangled.

Comment: @Mark S. Everitt I have no idea. I was under impression that the OP was asking only about separate Xfig pictures not overlays.

Comment: Overlays are a stressed point in the question. This is trawling back some years to when I used xfig as a student. I remember LaTeX making it in as simple text, and I guess that would be placed without changes into an EPS file upon conversion. If that is the case then the LaTeX snippets would survive and your suggestion could work perfectly. I just don't happen to have xfig installed or any old `fig` files to test it on!

Answer (score 2):

To avoid that pgf error, simply add the tikz arrows library:

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
```